# Regex to correct php code - subsitute string excluding some cases

Tags: php, regex, netbeans

I'm reviewing a my old php software and I need to do some general corrections. I'm trying to do some of them automatically by regex, but in some cases without success. I use Netbeans.

I need to substitute all:

```
$line[word_test]
```

with

```
$line['word_test']
```

excluding the case where word_test is a var (i.e. $abc) or a number or contains the string "const"

I tried with several regex like

```
\$line\[[^'|\$|constan](.*)\]
```

but without success.
I need both the regex to write in the "Containing Text" field and that one to write in "Replace with" field of Netbeans replace functionality.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One option is to use capturing group with a negative lookahead.

```
(\$line\[)(?!\d|\$\w|[^\]]*const)([^\]]+)(\])
```

**Explanation**

- `(\$line\[)` Capture group 1, match `$line[`
- `(?!` Negative lookahead, assert what is directly to the right is not

  - `\d|\$\w|[^\]]*const` Match either a digit, `$` followed by a word char or `const`
- `)` Close lookahead
- `([^\]]+)` Capture group 2, match any char except `]`
- `(\])` Capture group 3, match `]`

[Regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/xQ76Gx/1)

In the replacement use the 3 capturing groups

```
$1'$2'$3
```

In case there is an already existing format of `$line['word_test1']` as [@Nigel Ren](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1213708/nigel-ren) points out in the comment, you could extend the negative lookahead:

```
(\$line\[)(?!'.*?'\]|\d|\$\w|[^\]]*const)([^\]]+)(])
```

[Regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/CpaiC2/1)

Comment: Not sure if the code needs to cope with ignoring any existing `$line['word_test1']` strings in the code.

Comment: @NigelRen That is a good point, I will add an update for that case.